# How to configure Reverse proxy for nodejs project and virtualhost for wordpress project

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

My Objectives:

I want to run the main website like http://dev.abc.com, which is a Node.js project. I ran the `app.js` through `pm2` and configured the reverse proxy in virtual host in Apache which is working perfectly fine.

Here is the code:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName dev.abc.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

My second object

There is another project in WordPress. Its path is `/var/www/html/blog`. I want to open that blog which is in WordPress setup like http://dev.abc.com/blog.

I wrote the code as below:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog

    <Directory /var/www/html/blog>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        Require all granted
    </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
```

But did not work. Whenever I try to hit it http://dev.abc.com/blog it shows 404 not found page.

How to achieve that thing?

Notes:

- OS Ubuntu 14.05
- Web Server apache2 nodejs for main website
  WordPress for /blog php 5.6

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are you *really* using Ubuntu 14.05? Because there no such version and 14.04 is very much EOL (2) Is the `<VirtualHost *:80>` at the end of your second configuration file accurate? Or is that a bad copy/paste job? It should be `</VirtualHost>` at the end of *both* your Apache `.conf` files.

Comment: I don't see a servername setting in your virtual configuration to allow apache to know which site it should be serving, did you just not copy it?

Comment: that as a bad copy paste issue ignore the os version also.